# "Clicking the X" in spectrwm

Tags: kill, window-manager, window

I'm happily using [spectrwm](https://github.com/conformal/spectrwm) and looking for a way to "click the X", to close a window *and kill the process*.

MOD+W just make the window disappear, the process keeps running.

> **Edit:**
>   That's intended behavior because MOD+W is for "iconify".

How can I stop programs that don't offer the infamous File->Exit or some similar way of closing them without `kill`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Mod + X" by default. Meaning if you haven't configured your keyboard shortcuts to something else.

Comment: well, that's embarrasing that I didn't find it myself / got something wrong with my question. I guess that I was pressing Mod + W the whole time...